# interprate the error in decompiled source

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, class, friend

I found some helpful code online where only the library file was provided and I recreated the source code but found a couple errors I am not sure of.

```
<StandardModule()> _
Friend NotInheritable Class CreateFiles
' Methods

' Fields
Private Shared Configuration As Configuration = New Configuration

' Nested Types
Private Delegate Sub showITDelegate(ByVal message As String)

<STAThread()> _
Public Shared Sub Main()
    CreateFiles.Configuration.ReadConfig()
    CreateFiles.DisplayConfig(CreateFiles.Configuration)
    CreateFiles.CreateFiles()
End Sub

Public Shared Sub CreateFiles()
```

I am trying to understand if there is another class missing because there are errors on the CreateFiles.* lines in the main and these reference subs within this very class:
CreateFiles has 'expression does not produce a value' under it.
Why would it reference itself and the methods and subs within the same class.

Comment: Pick better names.  Avoid giving a Sub the same name as the class that it is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it looks at the `Sub CreateFiles()` rather than the class. And a sub (routine) doesn't return any value. You could remove the (first) `CreateFiles` in the `Main` subroutine.

This should work:

```
<StandardModule()> _
Friend NotInheritable Class CreateFiles
' Methods

' Fields
Private Shared Configuration As Configuration = New Configuration

' Nested Types
Private Delegate Sub showITDelegate(ByVal message As String)

<STAThread()> _
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Configuration.ReadConfig()
    DisplayConfig(Configuration)
    CreateFiles()
End Sub

Public Shared Sub CreateFiles()
```

Given that you don't have a problem anywhere else.

Comment: thanks for your response. I initially thought of that but then wondered why someone would code like that or is this just a result of the decompiler I used.

Comment: It might be indeed a result of the decompiler. (I don't know which one you used.)